# Updating android app in Google play requires change in both version and versioncode?

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to update an app on Google PLay. Do i need to update both?

`android:versionName and
  android:versionCode`

I updated without changing the versionName, I ONLY changed the versionCode. Does it count as an upgrade? Will the user see the update available? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the user will still receive an update.

`versionCode` is the deciding factor when Google Play issues updates. Your `versionName` can stay the same for your app's entire existence, and Google Play will still issue updates.

Comment: Thanks Raghav for the quick reply! :)

Comment: but it is a good practice to update the version name as well so that users don't have 20 updates but still see version 1.0. It is also convenient for bug reports.

Answer (score 0):

VersionCode needs to be changed. It's the value used by Android to determine your version. VersionName is shown in the playstore and is only used for users to see the update count.

Users will see the update but won't see a change in version number.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In Google play , The required change is **versionCode** version name is used only to track what version is listed on play store , in other words it is for users